# Как скопировать экземпляр HttpClient без зависимости

Tags: c#

Мне нужно создать несколько отдельных копий основного HttpClient, но при каких-либо изменениях копий, основной client тоже получает эти изменения. Как убрать эту зависимость?

Comment: Потому что вы копируете ссылку на объект

Comment: Сколько копий надо, столько раз `new` и делайте. Склонировать просто так не получится. Читать про ссылочные типы, все классы - ссылочные типы.